# strange value when print linked list values in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, token, c-strings

I made an application in C using Linked List the app taking a data from stander input line by line and enter each word to the linked list and at the end print all these words without any duplicate so i make this code

```
//linked list
typedef struct NODE Node;
struct NODE{
  char *item;
  Node *next;
};
 //insert function
bool insert(Node** head_ref, char *new_string)
{
    /* allocate node */
struct NODE* new_node = (struct NODE*) malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

/* put in the data  */
new_node->item = new_string;

/* link the old list off the new node */
new_node->next = (*head_ref);

/* move the head to point to the new node */
(*head_ref) = new_node;
return true;
}
// tells us whether or not the given string is in the list
bool search(struct NODE *head, char *target)
{
    struct NODE *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->item == target)
            return true;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}
// declare of the linked list 
Node *LinkedList = NULL;
//function used to read the stander input from the user
void loadFile()
{
#define LINE_SIZE 256
  char input[LINE_SIZE];
  char *token = NULL;

  while ( fgets( input, LINE_SIZE, stdin ) )
  {
    // parse the data into separate elements
    token = strtok( input, " \t\n" );
    while ( token )
    {
        if (!search(LinkedList, token)) {
            insert(&LinkedList, token);
            //puts("insert");
        }
        else {
            //printf("Not insert\n");
        }


      token = strtok( NULL, " \t\n" );
    }
  }
}
```

this function to print all the words in the list

```
void Print(Node* head)
{
    Node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", current->item);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

when i print the words at the end it give me strange characters this my main

```
int main()
{
  loadFile();
  Print(LinkedList);

  return 0;
}
```

i stop input by using cntrl + Z on windows

Comment: What's an example of the expected and actual output?

Comment: regarding: `struct NODE
{
  char *item;
  Node *next;
};` It is best to replace `Node *next;` with `struct NODE *next;` and place the `typedef` after the definition of the struct

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: in the function: `insert()`, this statement: `new_node->item = new_string;` results in all the `item` pointer to point to the start of the input buffer (so they will all point to the same thing)  They each need to point to the unique string. Suggest: `new_node->item = strdup(new_string);  if( !new_node->item ) { // then strdup failed, handle error, cleanup, call `exit()` }`

Comment: the posted code fails to return the allocated memory to the heap.  (this is normally done via calling `free()` for each pointer returned from a call to `malloc(), `calloc()`. )  The result of not making the calls is memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're not actually allocating space for the item, you're just reusing the same buffer.  `insert(&LinkedList, strdup(token));`

You are also comparing pointers not strings

`if (current->item == target)`

`if (strcmp(current->item, target)==0)`

Although with the current bug it will probably actually work!

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. corrects all the problems highlighted in the comments to the question
3. properly checks for errors
4. documents why each header file is included
5. consistently indents the code, with each indent level being 4 spaces
6. contains appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.
7. separates code blocks (for, if, else, whle, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line
8. performs the desired functionality

and now the proposed code:

```
//linked list
#include <stdio.h>    // fgets(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // malloc(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdbool.h>  // bool, true, false
#include <string.h>   // strtok(), strdup()

#define LINE_SIZE 256


struct NODE
{
  char *item;
  struct NODE *next;
};
typedef struct NODE Node;


// declare of the linked list
Node *LinkedList = NULL;


// prototypes
void insert( Node **head_ref, char *new_string );
bool search( Node *head, char *target );
void Print ( Node *head );
void loadFile( void );


 //insert function
void insert( Node **head_ref, char *new_string )
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct NODE* new_node =  malloc( sizeof(struct NODE) );
    if( !new_node )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    /* put in the data  */
    new_node->item = strdup( new_string );
    if( !new_node->item )
    {
        perror( "strdup failed" );
        // TODO: cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, strdup successful

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}


// tells us whether or not the given string is in the list
bool search( Node *head, char *target )
{
    struct NODE *current = head;

    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        if ( strcmp( current->item, target) == 0 )
            return true;

        current = current->next;
    }

    return false;
}


//function used to read 'stdin' from the user
void loadFile()
{
    char input[ LINE_SIZE ];
    char *token = NULL;

    while ( fgets( input, LINE_SIZE, stdin ) )
    {
        // parse the data into separate elements
        token = strtok( input, " \t\n" );

        while ( token )
        {
            if ( !search( LinkedList, token ) )
            {
                insert( &LinkedList, token );
                //puts("insert\n");
            }

            else
            {
                //printf("Not insert\n");
            }

            token = strtok( NULL, " \t\n" );
        }
    }
}


//this function to print all the words in the list
void Print( Node* head )
{
    Node *current = head;

    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", current->item );
        current = current->next;
    }
}


//when i print the words at the end it give me strange characters this my main
int main( void )
{
    loadFile();
    Print( LinkedList );

    return 0;
}
```

a simple run of the program results in the following:

```
1
3
5
5
4
2
0   (at this point, used <ctrl-d> (linux) to end the input
0
2
4
5
3
1
```

a second simple run of the program

```
first second second first third forth
forth
third
second
first
```